# Why do these following query executions differ in node-mssql?

Tags: node.js, node-mssql

I have a NodeJS application and I'm trying to insert into a table on a mssql db using the node-mssql package.

I stumbled across the following behaviour when building the sql statement with the data to be inserted provided as an object.

```
const request = conn.request();
return request.query`INSERT INTO sometable (${Object.keys(data).join(',')}) VALUES (${Object.values(data)});`;
```

This approach leads to the following error `Invalid column name '@param1'.`

However, when doing this...:

```
const request = conn.request();
const query = `INSERT INTO sometable (${Object.keys(data).join(',')}) VALUES (${Object.values(data)});`;
return request.query(query);
```

...it works as expected and I have no idea what the difference is.

If anyone has an explanation I'd be glad to hear it.